# ICE connection state remains as “Checking”

Tags: google-chrome, voip, webrtc, stun

I am trying to make a call from sipml5 to voIP softphone and after the signalling is done, 
I am facing an issue with ICE connection state remains as “Checking” and the request / response (binding Success) is being re-transmitted.

I use Chrome Version 33.0.1750.146 (binary). I believe this version will include the libjingle patches (port.cc, port.h and basicportallocator.cc).

For testing purpose, I have used PJNATH ICEdemo for ice answering
logs have been uploaded on MARCH 4 2014 in-
https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=2613

Please help me find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a signalling issue. Solved it by adding rtcp-mux to sip sdp.